# GoogleAppEngine: Python Files are Cached, HTML are fine

Tags: google-app-engine

I've read through GAE documentation and other Stack Overflow questions and i'm not seeing anything similar to my issue and it's driving me crazy.

When I start app engine and make some changes to my report.py file, I then go to my browser and load /r with the URL variables and everything loads fine.

I then go back to my report.py and make a change and nothing shows up. I tried adding in a logging.info() which didn't show up in the logging area of GAE, then even tried hard coding once of the variable i pass to HTML. nothing updates. I then straight up moved the python file to reportKEEP.py and the request still runs fine. I.e. GAE is caching my .py file and there's nothing I can do to un-cache besides stopping the app and then running it again. When I do reset the app via the launcher the changes show up fine (or the error that no report.py found).

I also tried updating the html file and that updates fine so I know that's working, it's just the .py file getting cached.

Please let me know what else I can provide to help you help me.

Everything i've read in the docs about caching is about static files and the py is not one of those.

Thanks!

Comment: See [Python not interpreting changed files, using obsolete .pyc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5629135/python-not-interpreting-changed-files-using-obsolete-pyc)

Comment: hi vladr, i just read that and I tried removing the .pyc to no avail. the pyc and py are all on the same system. is there somewhere else the py is cached? How could i remove the pyc file and the request still work?

Comment: @vladr forgot to give you the mention :)

Comment: Which version of App Engine SDK are you using? There is a known bug for the latest SDK to not always load the latest version of code and needs to be restarted.

Answer (score 0):

Well i have no idea what was causing this but at least i figured out a workaround.

I did look at the link from vlad and I knew this wasn't a timestamp issues. I basically rebuilt my entire app engine environment from scratch including uninstalling and reinstalling GAE launcher, running from command line, and even eventually got my wife's macbook pro and did a completely fresh install. Still no luck, everytime i edited that damn report.py file, the changes wouldn't be reflected on the front end. Could even remove the file and the request would generate fine, meanign the file was cached somewhere deep in GAE.

Eventually i just said screw it, copied the .py into a new file (reports.py) and edited the main.py to point to the new file. VIOLA! works perfectly, updating the front end with new data and print outs instantly.

If i had to guess it may have been because in my main.py i had a forwarding handler for both /r and /report pointing to the same report.py file, but i'm too scared to mess with it.