# Is it safe to remove all python *.pyc files to force usage of new code?

Tags: python, pyc

I have a server running a Python app. I'm updating the app's code manually via sftp.
Is it safe to remove the `*.pyc` files that are automatically created in my app's dir?

Comment: 1. Yes. You don't have to reboot, if the .pyc is missing it will be automatically generated. Note that .pyc are automatically regenerated if its .py is newer. 2. [How can I manually generate a .pyc file from a .py file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5607283/how-can-i-manually-generate-a-pyc-file-from-a-py-file)

Comment: compileall : http://stackoverflow.com/a/22779209/2142994

Comment: Possibly related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5629135/python-not-interpreting-changed-files-using-obsolete-pyc

Comment: In my personal opinion is not needed, anyway you can use this to recompile all the python files on filesystem find / -iname '*.py' | xargs python -m py_compile

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it's safe. Use `pyclean` command

> Usage: pyclean [-p PACKAGE] [DIR_OR_FILE]

```
pyclean .
```

Comment: `Command 'pyclean' not found, but can be installed with:

sudo apt install python2
`